# Merging data on Opportunities from multiple reports

Tags: opportunity, custom-field

I am struggling to understand Salesforce features with respect to merging information from multiple reports. Specifically, how does one lookup information on a given Opportunity or Account from other types of reports, such as Activity or Campaign reports.

For example, say I would like to create a variable in an Opportunity report indicating the first date in which an Opportunity was associated with a particular campaign? Is this possible in Salesforce?

Comment: Can you clarify if you are looking to do this exclusively in Analytics (the Reports tab) or if you are able to expend resources on custom logic/code? As the answerer below notes, this cannot be done through analytics alone.

Comment: I can definitely experiment with custom fields and logic though ultimately I was hoping the information could be summarized in a report format. Direction to any resources or examples would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for can be accomplished, but not through analytics alone. The out of the box analytics engine from Salesforce gives you the ability to do cross/joined reports; however, if I am interpreting what you're looking for correctly, what you really need to know is if a particular opportunity has met certain criteria. I would approach this through the use of custom fields. I have done something similar to prevent contract activations if certain criteria has not been meet. I used a trigger to "check" some custom field boxes that were then used as a part of a validation rule.

You will need three custom checkbox fields, one for each of the items you want to validate. The most difficult is going to be the one for task.

Since you want to report on certain types of tasks being related to the opportunity, you would likely have to use a trigger or a process builder process. If you are not a coder, then process builder would be your best bet; however, keep in mind that process builder is not bulk ready! So if you have the need to update/insert multiple tasks simultaneous via the data loader or via a scheduled load, you may need to limit your scope size (e.g. 100 records instead of 200).

Assuming you can work around that limitation, you'll need to have a task formula field of type checkbox, call it "Opportunity?", and it should have the following formula:

```
begins(whatId,"006")
```

This will return if the item set is of type opportunity (opportunities always begin with 006, which is its identifier).

Then create a process builder, have it check if the "Opportunity?" field is true and the type is what ever you need it to be.

Note, you can also use the the "formula evaluates as true" function of process builder instead of the custom field that I mentioned. The formula would be something like this:

```
CONTAINS([Task].Subject, "Testing") && BEGINS([Task].WhatId, "006")
```

That would help you by not requiring a custom field, but I'm not sure how comfortable with editing formulas you might be.

You can then have a flow, which will take the id of the opportunity as a input variable, which does a simple record update. Something like this:
[image: Opportunity Record Update]

If you want it to be safe, you can add a decision before it that checks if the opportunity ID is null, that's upto you though.

After you do that, the rest should be doable with simple workflow rules as they all reside within the opportunity. You can have a workflow rule that checks if the stage = 'blah' and the stage checkbox custom field is "false", then have it set it to true. Same with the campaign. If campaign.name = "blah" or campaign.type = "blah" and campaign checkbox custom field is "false", set it to true.

Now you have three custom checkbox custom fields, one for task, stage and campaign. You can then create a report which displays them as true or false, or filter to show only those that are true.

Hope that helps you!